Solana BigTable missing rows?
I decided to figure out BigQuery Solana Instance, and wrote a test query like this:
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.crypto_solana_mainnet_us.Accounts`
WHERE
  pubkey = "4iSRTaE8SmpaCUwHnTVkDBpFGaqVJJXtbBvijRdFapgq"

4iSRTaE8SmpaCUwHnTVkDBpFGaqVJJXtbBvijRdFapgq is a random address from Mainnet Beta, it has a small SOL balance, but the result of this query gives me 0 results.
Am I doing something wrong or do I not understand the mechanics of how BigQuery works?

I am from Bitquery. You can try Bitquery's Solana GraphQL API.
Here are the docs.
https://docs.bitquery.io/v1/docs/Examples/Solana/instructions
https://bitquery.io/blog/solana-api
